# Ссылка на обьект в классе C++

Tags: c++, указатели, ссылки

Возник такой тривиальный вопрос. Как хранить ссылку на обьект в классе?

К примеру, у меня есть класс точка(point), и есть класс ребро(edge). В Edge у меня два поля(point). Я инициализирую ребро двумя точками, к примеру, p1 и p2 (Edge e(p1, p2)). Вопрос: Можно ли сделать в C++ так, что бы при изменении точек p1 и p2 менялись значения и в edge?
К примеру, у меня есть две точки: p1(0, 0) и p2(5, 5). Я делаю из них ребро Edge e(p1, p2). Ок. Теперь, я хочу точку p1 сдвинуть на 10 по оси X, следовательно ребро должно измениться и стать другим после изменения точки p1.
Как это сделать?

```
class Edge
{
  public:
    Edge(const point &a, const point &b);
  private:
    point& org;
    point& dest;
};
```

Comment: Минус что ссылок, что указателей - что если что-то произойдет с точкой, будет висячая ссылка в никуда... Может, подумать о применении `shared_ptr`?

Comment: Можно и туда покопать)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это можно сделать, например, следующим образом. Только вам в явном виде надо будет определить конструктор копирования и копирующий оператор присваивания, или определить их как удаленные.

```
class Edge
{
  public:
    Edge( point &a, point &b) : org( a ), dest( b )
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^    
    {
    }
  private:
    point& org;
    point& dest;
};
```

Либо, например, как

```
class Edge
{
  public:
    Edge( point &a, point &b) : org( a ), dest( b )
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^    
    {
    }
  private:
    const point& org;
    ^^^^^^^^^
    const point& dest;
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^
};
```

то есть в зависимости от того, может ли этот класс изменять точки, на которые ссылается.

Другой подход это объявить члены класса `Edge` объектами типа `std::reference_wrapper`.

Например,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

class Point
{
};

class Edge
{
public: 
    Edge( Point &p1, Point &p2 ) : rp1( p1 ), rp2( p2 )
    {
    }
private:
    std::reference_wrapper<Point> rp1;
    std::reference_wrapper<Point> rp2;
};

int main()
{
    Point p1, p2;

    Edge e( p1, p2 );
}
```

Comment: В общем задача состоит в том, что есть набор точек(фиксированный) и задана связь между ними ребрами. Мне нужно выполнять операции только на точках, и так, чтобы связь по прежнему оставалась между изначально соединенными точками.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ большое!!!

Comment: @rekrut Не за что. Спрашивайте еще.:)